# Table presentation in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I have written a table in beamer. The code is as under:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
            max width=.9\textwidth}{
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline 
                    \begin{tabular}{c}
                        XYZ\\ABC    
                    \end{tabular}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Number of Vehicles } & \begin{tabular}{c}
                    Monthly\\Saving     
                    \end{tabular} &
                    \begin{tabular}{c}
                        Improvement in\\  ABC (\%) 
                    \end{tabular} \\ 
                    \hline 
                    & PQR & ZXC &  &  \\ 
                    \hline 
                    140 & 61 & 41 & 4 & 12 \\ 
                    \hline 
                    150 & 83 & 61 & 4 & 12 \\ 
                    \hline 
                    170 & 124 & 12 & 4 & 12 \\ 
                    \hline 
                \end{tabular} 
            }
            \end{frame}

        \end{document}
```

I want to merge last three rows of 4th column so that the entry 4 shows up only once. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then `\hline` you can use `\cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
            max width=.9\textwidth}{
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline 
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    XYZ\\ABC    
  \end{tabular} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Number of Vehicles } &       
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    Monthly\\Saving     
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    Improvement in\\  ABC (\%) 
  \end{tabular} \\ 
  \hline 
  & PQR & ZXC &  &  \\ 
  \hline 
  140 & 61  & 41 &   & 12 \\ 
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5} 
  150 & 83  & 61 & 4 & 12 \\ 
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
  170 & 124 & 12 &   & 12 \\ 
  \hline 
\end{tabular} 
}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked fine for 4th column but does not work for 5th column.

Comment: Just remove `\cline{5-5}`